# MongoDB C++ Driver 2.5.5 build / usage with VC2010

Tags: c++, mongodb

I have a problem building the MongoDB C++ driver or the usage of the driver library.

I use the driver sources 2.5.5. I used scon with the followed parameters:

*scons.py --prefix=e:\mongo-client-install --full  install-mongoclient*

For me it seems everything works fine. I did not recognise any errors in the build process. The directory "mongo-client-install is generated and contains the headers and also the lib file.

When I include the headers and lib file to VC2010 the compiling itself generates no errors. During linking I get 3 link errors:

*1>MongoDriverTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual _*cdecl mongo::DBClientConnection::~DBClientConnection(void)" (*_imp_??1DBClientConnection@mongo@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function "void _*cdecl run(void)" (?run@@YAXXZ)
1>MongoDriverTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "*_declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl mongo::DBClientConnection::connect(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &)" (_*imp*?connect@DBClientConnection@mongo@@QEAAXAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function "void _*cdecl run(void)" (?run@@YAXXZ)
1>MongoDriverTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "*_declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl mongo::DBClientConnection::DBClientConnection(bool,class mongo::DBClientReplicaSet *,double)" (_*imp*??0DBClientConnection@mongo@@QEAA@_NPEAVDBClientReplicaSet@1@N@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl run(void)" (?run@@YAXXZ)*

Does anyone have an idea on hoe to use the current MongoDB C++ driver as precompiled  library? With the 2.4.x version of the MongoDB driver I did not have any problems crating the lib and using the driver. But since I'm setting up a new project I'd like to use the current MongoDB C++ driver.

---EDIT---
For clarification, SCON used VC2010 to build the driver lib, and the small application is also build with VC2010. The application is build directly in the IDE, the lib is added using pragma comment(lib, ...)

Comment: Does it build if you just use Visual Studio?

Comment: The driver itself was build using scons (with VC2010) and the test application itself was compiled within VC2010 ide.